# Method to open Phone app (Swift)

Tags: swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

What's the method to open the phone app with a populated number? I know how to do this for a text message with MFMessageCompose but would like to learn how for phone calls. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "tel://9999999999"))` will do the trick. I reccommend spending some more time searching next time before you ask a question as this has been asked several times.